# C# - Simple Count elements inside For each ()

Tags: c#

Is this the correct way to count the amount of elements displayed in a for each?:

```
 var sql = db.Query("SELECT * FROM UserProfiles WHERE FullName LIKE @0 AND Role = 'Student' ", search);

 @foreach (var nom in sql){
        if (nom.Count() == 1){
           @nom.Name + info
        }else{
           @nom.Name
        }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to get the count from `nom` instead of `sql`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking the count of `nom` instead of `sql`.

```
if (sql.Count() == 1){  // <= here
   @nom.Name + info  
}else{
   @nom.Name
}
```